# Does Covariance equal 0

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, covariance, bivariate-distributions

Let $U,V$ be a bivariate random variable with a continuous distribution and $f_{U,V}$ is the joint density of $(U,V)$. Suppose that $f_{U,V}(−u,v)=f_{U,V}(u,v)$ for all $u,v∈\mathbb{R}$, then $cov(U,V)$ must equal to zero.

I know that covariance equals zero when the two random variables are independent. However, I do not think this would help, as I would need $f_U$ and $f_V$ to check for independence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the covariance is $0$ if $U$ and $V$ have finite second moments. $\int \int uv f_{U,V} (u,v)dudv=\int \int -ab f_{U,V} (a,b) dadb$ by the change of variable $a=-u,b=v$. Hence, $E[UV]=0$. Also, $EU=0$ since $f_U$ is symmetric. Hence, $cov (U,V)= EUV-(EU)(EV)=0$.

Comment: ... assuming the mean and covariance exist